# Looking for a procedure to determine if a given SQL query is compatible with Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I realize there could be false positives due to dynamic query generation. So, a positive result does not guarantee the query is actually supported. However, the negative result should be 100% reliable.

There are ways to parse a T-SQL query and get back the respective AST.

For example:

1. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser

   - It seems possible that by providing [ParseOptions.CompatibilityLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.parseoptions.compatibilitylevel?view=sql-smo-150) equal to [DatabaseCompatibilityLevel.Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.common.databasecompatibilitylevel?view=sql-smo-150) we get the required compatibility level. However, the documentation is very sparse. Is it compatibility with the Azure SQL database or with the Managed SQL Server Instance? Or something else entirely?
2. https://www.nuget.org/packages/gudusoft.gsqlparser

   - From https://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-supported-databases.php seems they are unaware of the Azure SQL database flavor.

I wonder if anyone has faced this problem and how have you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [TransactSql ScriptDom .NET library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsqlparser?view=sql-dacfx-150) to parse dynamic SQL that target Azure SQL.

[Here](https://github.com/arvindshmicrosoft/SQLScriptDomSamples) you will find some quite simple examples to get started. Once you add the necessary references to ScriptDom, you can instantiate a TSqlParser class specific to the target version of SQL that you are working with. Currently for Azure SQL and SQL Server 2019, that would be the [TSqlParser150 class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.tsql150parser?view=sql-dacfx-160).

```
    using (var rdr = new StringReader(textBox1.Text))
    {
        IList<ParseError> errors = null;
        var parser = new TSql150Parser(true, SqlEngineType.All);
        var tree = parser.Parse(rdr, out errors);
        ...
```

Engine type = 2 means SQL Azure. For more information, visit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.sqlenginetype?view=sql-dacfx-preview).

Comment: TSql150Parser(true, SqlEngineType.All). EngineType = 2 is SQLAzure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.sqlenginetype?view=sql-dacfx-preview

Comment: I will give it a try. Does not seem there is a NuGet package for this, though.